# How to manage route if we need to visit Yogyakarta and Komodo Islands from Bali and then return to Bali?

Tags: planning, routes, indonesia

My girlfriend and I are travelling to Indonesia for 5 weeks this summer. We land and leave from Denpasar airport in Bali.

Here's the tricky bit - we want to visit Yogyakarta (west of Bali) and the Komodo Islands (east of Bali) - as well as points along the way.

The main sights for us are Ijen Crater and Mt. Bromo, so we are thinking of doing a guided tour that will drive us through those places from Bali all the way to Yogyakarta. Then we will probably have to take a flight from `JOG` to `DPS` to save time.

The only feasible route I can see is `DPS -> LBJ -> DPS -> JOG -> DPS`.

However, someone more knowledgable might be able to suggest a route more close to:

`DPS -> LBJ -> JOG -> DPS`?

Money isn't that much of an issue; my bigger concern is squeezing it all in the time frame - I appreciate I haven't give you all the details - keep in mind that we want to climb Mt. Rinjani as well for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 weeks is plenty for that trip, including Rinjani.
Several years ago I did a trip from Maumere to the Gili islands west of Lombok in 4 weeks, by (private, small tour group) bus and boat, 4 weeks of slow travel over the islands.
If you plan to use internal flights to bypass some islands and most boat travel, you've plenty of times to extend the trip further west in 5 weeks.

The boat tour to and around Komodo and Rinca will take 2-3 days (depending on the exact itinerary of course), half a day out, afternoon on Komodo, sleep on board, short crossing to Rinca, visit there, and back to LBJ for example.
While interesting there's not all that much to see or do in the national park, so that's plenty of time for most people.

DPS-LBJ-JOG-LBJ is certainly an option.

Comment: Thanks. Given that we might have the time, how much far west of Labuan Bajo do you recommend going? Any particular places?

Comment: well, Labuan Bajo is on the west coast of Flores, so you'd probably want to go east. Ende and Mount Kelimutu is an option but might be a bit far depending on how much time you want to spend elsewhere... Or add some time on Lombok, which is definitely worth a visit. See if you can get a flight from LBO to somewhere on Lombok, visit mount Rinjani, maybe relax a few days on the Gili islands (good snorkeling there too).

Comment: Sorry I meant East! But anyhow, it sounds like all options east of Labuan Bajo are a bit far, as I suspected. We are already planning on climbing Rinjani and chilling around the Gili islands so I'm glad to hear you suggesting them. Many thanks.

Comment: check my photoset from the trip at http://captainduckman.com/I2012/  Page 10 starts the section from Lubuan Bajo to Komodo.

Answer (score 0):

There are no non-stop flights between LBJ and JOG as you have discovered. There are from Jakarta, but that is no better than connecting in Denpasar.

If the 7 hour layovers sound undesireable, perhaps consider inserting a Bali stay between the adventures.  Arrive in Bali do something, fly east to adventure one, fly back to Bali explore central Bali, fly west to adventure two, fly back explore the rest of Bali.